# grouping several numbered variables in a python set

Tags: python

hello everyone I am trying to make an app for face recognition with the face_recognition libraries in python, for now, i want to create a set of several numbered variables. suppose i have created the variables in this way

```
for j in range(1,500):
    exec('var_%d = face_recognition.load_image_file(path)' % (j))
```

so i get these variables

```
var_1, var_2, var3, ... , var_500
```

in python avoiding to write then one by one, how can i make a set like this one:

```
known_encodings = [var_1, var_2, var_3, ... , var_500]
```

edit:

the code that im using is here

```
clases = '/home/workstation/Desktop/fv/foto ideal/known/'
predictor = '/home/workstation/Desktop/fv/foto ideal/unknown/'
from os import listdir
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):


    names = [l for l in listdir(clases)]

    j=0
    for name in names:
        try:
            exec('known_%d = face_recognition.load_image_file(clases+ "%s")' %(j,name))
            exec('biden_encoding_%d = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_%d)[0]'%(j,j))
            print(j)
            j +=1
        except:
            pass

knowns_encodings = [biden_encoding_0,biden_encoding_1,biden_encoding_2,biden_encoding_3,biden_encoding_4,biden_encoding_5,biden_encoding_6,biden_encoding_7,biden_encoding_8,biden_encoding_9,biden_encoding_10,biden_encoding_11,biden_encoding_12,biden_encoding_13,biden_encoding_14,biden_encoding_15,biden_encoding_16,biden_encoding_17,biden_encoding_18,biden_encoding_19,biden_encoding_20,biden_encoding_21,biden_encoding_22,biden_encoding_23,biden_encoding_24,biden_encoding_25,biden_encoding_26,biden_encoding_27,biden_encoding_28,biden_encoding_29,biden_encoding_30,biden_encoding_31,biden_encoding_32,biden_encoding_33,biden_encoding_34,biden_encoding_35,biden_encoding_36,biden_encoding_37,biden_encoding_38,biden_encoding_39,biden_encoding_40,biden_encoding_41,biden_encoding_42,biden_encoding_43,biden_encoding_44,biden_encoding_45,biden_encoding_46,biden_encoding_47,biden_encoding_48,biden_encoding_49,biden_encoding_50,biden_encoding_51,biden_encoding_52,biden_encoding_53,biden_encoding_54,biden_encoding_55,biden_encoding_56,biden_encoding_57,biden_encoding_58,biden_encoding_59,biden_encoding_60,biden_encoding_61,biden_encoding_62,biden_encoding_63,biden_encoding_64,biden_encoding_65,biden_encoding_66,biden_encoding_67,biden_encoding_68,biden_encoding_69,biden_encoding_70,biden_encoding_71,biden_encoding_72,biden_encoding_73,biden_encoding_74,biden_encoding_75,biden_encoding_76,biden_encoding_77,biden_encoding_78,biden_encoding_79,biden_encoding_80,biden_encoding_81,biden_encoding_82,biden_encoding_83,biden_encoding_84,biden_encoding_85,biden_encoding_86,biden_encoding_87,biden_encoding_88,biden_encoding_89,biden_encoding_90,biden_encoding_91,biden_encoding_92,biden_encoding_93,biden_encoding_94,biden_encoding_95,biden_encoding_96,biden_encoding_97,biden_encoding_98,biden_encoding_99,biden_encoding_100,biden_encoding_101,biden_encoding_102,biden_encoding_103,biden_encoding_104,biden_encoding_105,biden_encoding_106,biden_encoding_107,biden_encoding_108,biden_encoding_109,biden_encoding_110,biden_encoding_111,biden_encoding_112,biden_encoding_113,biden_encoding_114,biden_encoding_115,biden_encoding_116,biden_encoding_117,biden_encoding_118,biden_encoding_119,biden_encoding_120,biden_encoding_121,biden_encoding_122,biden_encoding_123,biden_encoding_124,biden_encoding_125,biden_encoding_126,biden_encoding_127,biden_encoding_128,biden_encoding_129,biden_encoding_130,biden_encoding_131,biden_encoding_132,biden_encoding_133,biden_encoding_134,biden_encoding_135,biden_encoding_136,biden_encoding_137,biden_encoding_138,biden_encoding_139,biden_encoding_140,biden_encoding_141,biden_encoding_142,biden_encoding_143,biden_encoding_144,biden_encoding_145,biden_encoding_146,biden_encoding_147,biden_encoding_148,biden_encoding_149]

unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(predictor+"12.jpg")
unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]
results = face_recognition.compare_faces([knowns_encodings], unknown_encoding, tolerance=0.50)

print(results)
```

Comment: There's never a reason to make variables named like this. Just put the values in a list and access them with `known_encodings[n]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the use case for this. If you provide context, we can help provide a better result.

but answer to your question would be something like

```
for i in range(1,501)]:
    exec("var_{0} = None".format(i) )
```

Edits after more context provided above and in comments-->

try replacing

```
exec('known_%d = face_recognition.load_image_file(clases+ "%s")' %(j,name))
exec('biden_encoding_%d = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_%d)[0]'%(j,j))
```

with this

```
known_dict[j] = face_recognition.load_image_file(clases+name)
known_dict[j] = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_dict[j])
```

and of course, make sure to initialize:
 so up front

```
known_dict = {}
biden_dict = {}
```

Comment: thanks man, the problem here is that the var_0 and so on, are strings, like ["var_0", var_1", "var_2"....], these var_n should be the variables that contains the face encoding, not just the text "var_n" thanx for the help

Comment: Got it. Why do you want them as variables? It would be cleaner (and easier for you to reference) if you throw them in a dictionary. IE {"var_x" : result_x, "var_y" : result_y }

Comment: it is possible with `exec` but it's not the best idea... same loop but  `exec("var_{0} = None".format(i) )`

Comment: it is because the var_x should pass through compare_faces, but in order to do so, i need the make a set that contain all the var_x

Comment: couldn't var_x just be a reference to the dictionary? so instead of `compare_faces(var_x)` you just write `compare_faces(d["var_x"])`If you have more code to look at, we could help better :)

Comment: i added the code that im using, the dictionary option sound nice but it will work whit my code?

Comment: so `exec` is almost always avoidable and not usually considered good practice. What you can do is `known_dict[j] = face_recognition.load_image_file(clases+name)` . Similiar throughout. Does that make sense?

Comment: Then when you need to reference, instead of `"known_%d" % value` you just write `known_d[value]`

Comment: I updated the post so its more clear. let me know if that helps :)